# Using incremental number as GetHashCode return value

Tags: c#, hash, unique

I want to make every instance of a class `X` having a unique ID.
I'm doing this using a incremented number:

```
class X {
    private int id;
    private static int instanceCounter = 0;

    public X() {
        id = Interlocked.Increment(ref instanceCounter);
    }

    //...
}
```

The objects are also used as keys in dictionaries, so I thought I could return `id` from `GetHashCode()`.

```
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return id;
    }
```

I'm aware of [Eric Lippert's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx), but it always talks about calculating hashs from multiple data stored in the object.
In my case, the only 'unique' data is `id`.

**So the question is:

Is there something I haven't thought about with this approach?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want each object to be distinct (so not equal to any other object) then just don't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` at all. The default is to give a "probably unique" hash code, which is all you need to narrow the choices down - and `Equals` will use reference identity, which is what you want. There's no need to have a separate `id` field, just for equality.

If you *do* need the `id` field for other reasons, you can certainly return it from `GetHashCode` - I would suggest making it a readonly field to make your intentions clear though.

Note that hash codes should never be used as a *definite* positive equality check anyway - they're only used to rule out instances which are definitely *not* equal to each other.

Comment: How is the default `GetHashCode` implemented? I get stuck at `[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]` ...

Comment: @joe: Yes, it's internal, effectively. You don't need to worry about it. If you need to obtain that hash code even when you're overriding `Object.GetHashCode`, you can always use `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(object)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just concerned about Equals() working correctly you can override the GetHashCode like

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return 0;
}
```

Meaning Equals() has to be called every time; which is fine logic-wise, but may lead into problems performance-wise (this will efficiently make any hashtable with this class to have retrieval complexity O(n) instead of O(1)); however for small list (tens of items) it should be fine.